# Strange behavior when using incell editing in cell edit mode with filter in Primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an issue when I use a datatable with a filter and cellEditor. When filter 'on', I mean there's some value in it, cell editing works fine only few first attempts, 'onCellEdit' being call when I exit from cell. But after two successful editing begins strange behavior. Method 'onCellEdit' called when I enter the edit mode in cell and cell 'closed' immediately after it. What's wrong with my code?

I use PF 5.1 and editing mode is cell editing:

> "Another option for incell editing is cell editing, in this mode a
>   cell switches to edit mode when it is clicked, losing focus triggers
>   an ajax event to save the change value."

Thank you.

**UPDATE: This behavior begins when I entered in edit mode in one cell and after making change I clicked on another change before submitting my changes by pressing enter, if prior to enter another cell I press enter, everything in fine.**

**Update2: possible it's connected to this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=3467).**

```
...
          <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
            listener="#{importsBean.onCellEdit(contact)}"
            oncomplete="PF('contacts').filter()"
            update=":form:messages name number description" process="@this" />


           <p:column id="name" 
                headerText="Name">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText id="name" value="#{contact.name}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{contact.name}" style="width:100%" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
...
```

Comment: Hello, i have the same problem, do u solve it?

Comment: @Mariah, unfortunately not. If you will able to solve it please post your answer here, I set aside this project but will need to implement it in a near future.

Comment: well its not exactly the case that you expose, but the behavior its the same... i think its a bug of prime

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, I also faced same problem. Please let me know once it's been solved.

Comment: @JoyalGeorge, we've abandoned JSF since then and moved to Angular, so it hasn't been solved and won't be solved by me at least. Btw, this issue was one of the small issues which lead us to leave JSF.